# Zend framework - how to write group by query

Tags: zend-framework

I use zend framework and can't write in model next sql query:

```
SELECT `id_user`,`system_role`,count(`system_role`)
FROM `favorites` 
group by `id_user`,`system_role`
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Table('favorites');
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('favorites', array('id_user', 'system_role', 'COUNT(system_role)'))
    ->group('id_user', 'system_role');
```